# Merge tables together in matlab

Tags: matlab, merge

How do I merge two tables together?

Table 1:

```
LastName     Age    Weight    Smoker
__________    ___    ______    ______

'Smith'       38     176       true  
'Johnson'     43     163       false 
'Williams'    38     131       false
```

Table 2:

```
LastName     Age    Weight    Smoker
__________    ___    ______    ______
'Jones'       40     133       false 
'Brown'       49     119       false
```

into:

```
LastName     Age    Weight    Smoker
__________    ___    ______    ______

'Smith'       38     176       true  
'Johnson'     43     163       false 
'Williams'    38     131       false 
'Jones'       40     133       false 
'Brown'       49     119       false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this using:

```
   Complete_Table=[Table1;
                   Table2]
```

**Complete Code:-**

```
LastName = {'Smith';'Johnson';'Williams'};
Age = [38;43;38];
Weight = [176;163;131];
Smoker=logical([1;0;0]);
Table1 = table(LastName,Age,Weight,Smoker)

%Overwriting
LastName = {'Jones';'Brown'};
Age = [40;49];
Weight = [133;119];
Smoker=logical([0;0]);
Table2 = table(LastName,Age,Weight,Smoker)

Complete_Table=[Table1;
                Table2]
```

**Output:-**

```
Table1 = 

     LastName     Age    Weight    Smoker
    __________    ___    ______    ______

    'Smith'       38     176       true  
    'Johnson'     43     163       false 
    'Williams'    38     131       false 


Table2 = 

    LastName    Age    Weight    Smoker
    ________    ___    ______    ______

    'Jones'     40     133       false 
    'Brown'     49     119       false 


Complete_Table = 

     LastName     Age    Weight    Smoker
    __________    ___    ______    ______

    'Smith'       38     176       true  
    'Johnson'     43     163       false 
    'Williams'    38     131       false 
    'Jones'       40     133       false 
    'Brown'       49     119       false
```